# mongoose pre hook not getting triggered on save in typescript-node-mongoose application

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am using typescript, node and mongoose to create a music application. I have created schema as shown in the code and then attached pre-hook to it before creating the model. On save method the pre-hook is not getting called.

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";
import validator from 'validator';
import UserDocument from '../documents/UserDocument';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

const UserSchema = new Schema<UserDocument>({
    name:{type:String,required:true,trim:true},
    email:{type:String,required:true,trim:true,validate:(email:string)=>{
        if(!validator.isEmail(email)){
            throw new Error("Please provide valid email Id");
        }
    }},
    username:{type:String,required:true,trim:true},
    password:{type:String,required:true,trim:true,validate:(password:string)=>{
        if(!validator.isStrongPassword(password)){
            throw new Error("Please provide strong password");
        }
    }}
});

UserSchema.pre('save',async function(next){
    console.log('Save pre hook called!!!')
    const user = this;
    if(user.isModified('password')){
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password,8);
    }
    console.log(user.password);
    next();
})

export const User = mongoose.model('Users',UserSchema);
```

type here Package file

```
{
  "name": "music-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A react-node-mongo-typescript music application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon dist/js/index.js\"",
    "start": "node dist/js/index.js",
    "inspect":"node inspect dist/js/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "vinita",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^5.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.4-lts.1",
    "multer-gridfs-storage": "^5.0.2",
    "validator": "^13.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.14",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

Calling save method as follows:

```
app.post("/users",async(req:Request,res:Response)=>{
const requestBody = req.body as UserDocument
const newUser = new User(requestBody);
try {
    await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).send(newUser);
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
}
```

});

Have tried to declare schema first and the created model. Still facing the same issue. Can someone help with this issue

Comment: Can't reproduce it, how did you call the `user.save()` method?

Comment: @LinDu Please check edited post to know how I called user.save().